# Align text in a fixed space equally centered

Tags: alignment

```
\paragraph{Testing}
\begin{itemize}
  \item (Help)
  \item (Individual)
  \item (Test)
\end{itemize}
```

This gives me
[image]

I'm trying to align text inside parenthesis equally & center. Something like the below.
Tried `makebox` but I'm sure how to use it properly.

```
(   Help   )
(Individual)
(   Test   )
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\makebox[<width>]{...}` creates a box of fixed length and centres its content by default if the content is shorter then the box. However, you would need to "find" the correct value of the parameter `<width>`.

A more convenient macro is defined in `eqparbox`, that is `\eqmakebox[<label>]{...}`. The difference is you supply a label, e.g. `list`, instead of a length `<width>` and a length of all boxes corresponding to the same label `[list]` are calculated to fit the longest content.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{eqparbox}

\newcommand\mb[1]{(\eqmakebox[list]{#1})}

\begin{document}

\paragraph{Testing}
\begin{itemize}
\item \mb{Help}
\item \mb{Individual}
\item \mb{Test}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

#### Description

You can use a tabular environment for this.
The brackets are placed automatically for the first and last column.

I defined an environment `bracketitemize` and a command `\bitem` to make this more comfortable.

#### Result

[image]

#### Code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}

\newenvironment{bracketitemize}{%
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}%
    \begin{tabular}{ >{\textbullet\quad (} c c >{)} c }%
}{%
    \end{tabular}%
}

\newcommand{\bitem}[1]{%
    & #1 &\\%
}

\begin{document}

manually:

{
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
    \begin{tabular}{  >{\textbullet\quad (} c c >{)} c }
        & Help &\\
        & Individual &\\
        & Test &\\
    \end{tabular}
}

\medskip
With \texttt{bracketitemize}:

\begin{bracketitemize}
    \bitem{Help}
    \bitem{Individual}
    \bitem{Test}
\end{bracketitemize}

\end{document}
```